# Compiling Error Using Reference to Textfield Unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

**Solved: "Enter" should not be used for "GetKeyDown", instead it should be "Return"**

Hello I've been working on a Unity project, and I'm not sure if this is the right place, but I keep getting compiler errors when I attempt to run the following C# script. The movement script is functioning and didn't cause any errors, I only got the compiler error after adding the text scripts.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class MovementScript2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static int playersScore = 0;
    Text score;
   
    void Start()
    {
        score = GetComponent<Text> ();
    }
    public float moveSpeed = 15f;
    public float turnSpeed = 70f;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
            transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
            transform.Translate(-Vector3.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, -turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Enter))
            playersScore += 10;

            score.text = "Score: " + playersScore;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the compiler error say?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Unity, so I didn't realize how to use the error console for debugging. I think I figured it out now. The console is telling me there is an error with using "if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Enter))" since "Enter" is not defined for some reason. I'm not sure how to proceed.

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/487765087407439872/885334142013820958/unknown.png

Comment: That's quite alright, I see you tagged it as solved, it is best if you type KeyCode. and let intellisense fill it out to avoid mistakes like this

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It is exactly like the error message states: `KeyCode.Enter` doesn't exist.

I guess what you rather want to use is [`KeyCode.Return`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/KeyCode.Return.html)